# Import CMFCOutlookBar Class form VS 10 to VS 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, mfc

My Visual Studio version does not support this new MFC class. CMFCOutlookBar available only in VS 10. How can I import CMFCOutlookBar class file form VS 10 to my project ? 
The solution like "Buy VS 10!" does not fit for me.
If it is possible to import CMFCOutlookBar. Can any body share this files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it VS8 (VS 2005) or VS2008 (VS9)? The title and the tags say different things.

**In VS2008, with the [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986) you get the [MFC Feature Pack Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ea9ee2f-1062-4b71-b33b-43f4c94f013b%28v=vs.90%29), which include CMFCOutlookBar.**

Microsoft does not provide them for earlier versions of VS, as far as I know. So you may have to take a look at some third party classes, like [BCGSoft's classes](http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/bcgcontrolbar-tour.htm) (Microsoft's MFC Feature Pack is based on some of BCGSoft's classes) or [The Ultimate Toolbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20182/The-Ultimate-Toolbox-Home-Page)